# 2 domains 1 WP instalation in Cpanel

Tags: installation

Hy I have a hosting plan that allows me to hoste multiple domains, right now i own 2 domains one is a .ro and the other is .com.

Right now in my Cpanel with softacoulos i have one instalation of WP for my .com and one instalation for my .ro

It ok they both run fine but the plugins and all the other edits are taking long time to set-up properly, i was wondering if i can add to one instalation the other domain.

like this 
main wp instalation > 1.ro 2.com

I am new to wp!

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Obs

I would set it up as a Multisite.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network. Then I would map the domains to the correct site like here: https://wpengine.com/support/multisite-how-to-add-new-sites/.

Another option is to get [WPML](https://wpml.org/). This is, however, not free but very versatile when it comes to language switching and translating.

I hope this post helped you get a little further.

Kind regrds.